# JDBC SQL Server not returning all values of query

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc

I have a Java program that utilizes the JDBC and OpenCSV libraries. I've come across an issue where some rows of the query will be left out. For example, if I run the exact same query in the Java program and SQL Server Management Studio, SQLSMS would return anywhere between 1-10 more lines than the Java program. I suspect this has something to do with the JDBC, because I tried switching away from OpenCSV to write the files and the issue persisted. You can see the connection method and a querying method below:

Connection Method:

```
/********
 * Handles the DB connection
 */
private static Connection conn;
private static String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://10.9.32.46:1433;database=TechTracker;integratedSecurity=true";
@FXML
public static Connection connect() throws SQLException {
    try{
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver").newInstance();
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe){
        System.err.println("Error: "+cnfe.getMessage());
    }catch(InstantiationException ie){
        System.err.println("Error: "+ie.getMessage());
    }catch(IllegalAccessException iae){
        System.err.println("Error: "+iae.getMessage());
    }

    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
    return conn;
}
```

SQL Getter Method:

```
 public static void getHardware() throws SQLException {
    ResultSet rs = null;

    try {

        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connect().prepareStatement("SELECT        dbo.tbCustomers.CustomerName AS Organization, \n" +
                "                         CASE WHEN HardwareType = 2 THEN 'Managed Server' WHEN HardwareType = 1 THEN 'Managed Workstation' WHEN HardwareType = 3 THEN 'Managed Switch' WHEN HardwareType = 4 THEN 'Managed Switch' WHEN HardwareType\n" +
                "                          = 5 THEN 'Managed Router' WHEN HardwareType = 6 THEN 'Managed Firewall' WHEN HardwareType = 7 THEN 'Miscellaneous' WHEN HardwareType = 8 THEN 'Printer' WHEN HardwareType = 9 THEN 'Managed Access Point'\n" +
                "                          ELSE 'Managed Configuration' END AS configuration_type_name, { fn CONCAT(dbo.tbHardware.HardwareName, dbo.tbHardware.ModelNo) } AS model, dbo.tbHardwareSite.SerialNo AS serial_number, \n" +
                "                         dbo.RTF2Text(dbo.tbHardwareSite.SwitchRouterConfig) AS operating_system_notes, dbo.tbHardwareSite.PurchaseDate AS purchased_at, dbo.tbHardwareSite.InstallDate AS installed_at, \n" +
                "                         { fn CONCAT(dbo.tbHardwareSite.Hostname, SUBSTRING(dbo.RTF2Text(dbo.tbHardwareSite.Notes), 0, 2000)) } AS Notes, dbo.tbHardwareSite.IDTag AS hardware_name, \n" +
                "                         CASE WHEN tbHardwareSite.Inactive = 'TRUE' THEN 'Inactive' WHEN tbHardwareSite.Inactive = 'FALSE' THEN 'Active' END AS configuration_status_name, dbo.tbManufacturers.MftrName AS manufacturer_name, \n" +
                "                         dbo.tbSites.SiteName AS location, dbo.tbCustomers.CustomerID\n" +
                "FROM            dbo.tbHardwareSite INNER JOIN\n" +
                "                         dbo.tbHardware ON dbo.tbHardwareSite.HardwareID_FK = dbo.tbHardware.HardwareID INNER JOIN\n" +
                "                         dbo.tbManufacturers ON dbo.tbHardware.ManufacturerID_FK = dbo.tbManufacturers.MftrID INNER JOIN\n" +
                "                         dbo.tbSites ON dbo.tbHardwareSite.SiteID_FK = dbo.tbSites.SiteID INNER JOIN\n" +
                "                         dbo.tbCustomers ON dbo.tbSites.CustomerID_FK = dbo.tbCustomers.CustomerID\n" +
                Main.idlist+" AND  (dbo.tbHardwareSite.Inactive = 'FALSE') ");
        preparedStatement.setMaxRows(100000);
        rs =  preparedStatement.executeQuery();

        CSVWriter csvWriter = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\jtorgerson\\Desktop\\hard.csv"), ',');
        csvWriter.writeAll(rs, true);
    } catch (SQLException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }}
```

Please let me know if any more info or code is needed. Thank you in advance!

Comment: FYI, [3+ part naming on Columns will be Deprecated](https://wp.larnu.uk/3-part-naming-on-columns-will-be-deprecated/); stick to aliasing your objects and qualifying your columns with that alias.

Comment: @Larnu Good riddance!

Comment: Thank you, I was unaware of this. That is the way SQLSMS formats it so I just assumed it was the standard. Much appreciated. @Larnu

Comment: So just to confirm: if you capture your prepared statement, including the `Main.idlist` insertion, and execute it in SSMS you get different results from the same server, same instance and same database? Do any of the tables/views have row-level security?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Yes. But it was something to do with OpenCSV. There was another comment outlining the answer and how I had to make sure to flush the writer, as I was only closing it. Once I added "writer.flush();" it all worked. So nothing to do with JDBC.